# looking for cleaner code when embedding razor calls in text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization, razor

I used to have something like this:

```
We suggest you read our @Html.ActionLink("help page", "Help", "Home") before
proceeding.
```

nice and clean.  then I decided we needed to internationalise the app.  I couldn't figure out a better way to deal with the above than to store the following string in the resource file:

```
We suggest you read our [HelpPage] before proceeding.
```

and then on the view I have to do:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(this.Resource("Help").ToString()
   .Replace("[HelpPage]",
       @Html.ActionLink("help page", "Help", "Home").ToString()
   )
)
```

What other strategies can you use to internationalize using Razor?

`this.Resource()` is a page extension that calls `.GetLocalResourceObject()` and returns an `MvcHtmlString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here's what I ended up writing:

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Resource(
        this WebViewPage page, string key, 
        Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tokenMap
    ) {
        HttpContextBase http = page.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        string text = (string) http.GetLocalResourceObject(page.VirtualPath, key);
        return new TagReplacer(text, tokenMap).ToMvcHtmlString();
    }
```

where the tag replacements gets done like this:

```
public class TagReplacer
{
    Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tokenmap;
    public string Value { get; set; } 

    public TagReplacer(string text, Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tokenMap)
    {
        tokenmap = tokenMap;

        Regex re = new Regex(@"\[.*?\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Value = re.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(this.Replacer));
    }

    public string Replacer(Match m)
    {
        return tokenmap[m.Value.RemoveSet("[]")].ToString();
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString()
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(Value);
    }
}
```

so in my code I can now call it like this:

```
@{
   Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tagmap = new Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>() {
                { "HelpPage", Html.ActionLink("help page", "Help", "Home") }
            };
}
```

and elsewhere:

```
@this.Resource("Help", tagmap)
```

any suggestions for improvement most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate code-behind method that replaces any `[placeholder]`s with actual links, then call that helper in Razor views.

This will give you a single place to change the code that fills in the links.

Comment: sounds reasonable but I can't quite think it through... so I would have `@Html.MyFn("Help", @Html.ActionLink())`? this is really like templating... the above would be good for one "tag" replacement but if I had 2 it gets complicated... thoughts?

Comment: @ekkis: You should do the tag replacement in the function.

Comment: yes but the problem is that there's no good way to make that generic... unless I were to pass a dictionary where the term is the token to replace and the definition some piece of code to run e.g. `Dictionary<string, code> tags = new Dictionary<string, string>() { "Help", "@Html.ActionLink(...)" }; @Html.MyFn(tags)` where MyFn would read the second string and eval() it (somehow - I'm not yet that good with C# to know how)

Comment: @ekkis: Exactly.  IT should be a `Dictionary<string, Func<string, IHtmlString>>`; the values should be delegates that you can call with the `[contents]`.  This gives you a single place to put all of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Instead of using placeholders, I use the same formatting in my resource strings as if I were using `String.Format()`. 
An example of using this; my resource strings

```
LogOnText1 | Please enter your user name and password. {0} if you don't have an account.
LogOnText1Register | Register
```

and my view (razor):

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format(ViewRes.AccountStrings.LogOnText1,
                      Html.ActionLink(ViewRes.AccountStrings.LogOnText1Register, "Register")))
```

I think it's a bit cleaner

Comment: it's a decent approach but I've never been fond of the positionality of the approach.  SLaks' discussion actually ended up leading to a nice solution.  I'll answer it here for the sake of closing the issue