# Dynamic Razor code execution - how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, razor, execution

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181552/looking-for-cleaner-code-when-embedding-razor-calls-in-text) I wondered about cleaner code when internationalising an app.  that leads to this second query... supposing I wanted to call a function like this:

```
@Html.RenderWithTags("Help",
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { "HelpPage", "@Html.ActionLink(...)" }
)
```

such that I look up a string in my local resource file containing embedded "tags" e.g. resource name "Help" contains:

> We suggest you read our [HelpPage]
>   before proceeding

and then my .RenderWithTags() method will expand the tags but dynamically executing the code in the dictionary passed e.g. replace `[HelpPage]` with whatever `@Html.ActionLink(...)` produces.

I know I can use `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider().CreateCompiler()` to compile C# code on the fly, but what about Razor code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, the solution turned out pretty slick.  would not have been possible without SLaks, I'm much obliged for the help (though I didn't end up using inline helpers (but thanks for the intro (they're very cool))).
Now my page contains this:

```
@{
    Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tokenMap = new Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>() {
        {"HelpPage", Html.ActionLink("help page", "Help", "Home") }
    };
}
```

and somewhere below I have:

```
@this.Resource("Epilogue", tokenMap)
```

To accomplish this simplicity:

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Resource(this WebViewPage page, string key)
    {
        HttpContextBase http = page.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        string ret = (string) http.GetLocalResourceObject(page.VirtualPath, key);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(ret);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Resource(
        this WebViewPage page, string key, 
        Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tokenMap
    ) {
        HttpContextBase http = page.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        string text = (string) http.GetLocalResourceObject(page.VirtualPath, key);
        return new TagReplacer(text, tokenMap).ToMvcHtmlString();
    }
}
```

...and:

```
public class TagReplacer
{
    Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tokenmap;
    public string Value { get; set; } 

    public TagReplacer(string text, Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> tokenMap)
    {
        tokenmap = tokenMap;

        Regex re = new Regex(@"\[.*?\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Value = re.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(this.Replacer));
    }

    public string Replacer(Match m)
    {
        return tokenmap[m.Value.RemoveSet("[]")].ToString();
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString()
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(Value);
    }
}
```

...with a little extra help:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceSet(this string text, string set, string x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < set.Length; i++)
        {
            text = text.Replace(set[i].ToString(), x);
        }
        return text;
    }
    public static string RemoveSet(this string text, string set)
    {
        return text.ReplaceSet(set, "");
    }
}
```

comments or feedback on how it could have been better most welcome!

Answer (score 3):

This will be rather difficult to do.

Instead, you should put delegates in your dictionary.
For example:

```
new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>() { 
    { "HelpPage", () => Html.ActionLink(...).ToString() }
}
```

If you're creating the dictionary in a Razor page, you could also use [inline helpers](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/04/dissecting-razor-part-9-inline-helpers.html):

```
new Dictionary<string, Func<Something, HelperResult>>() { 
    { "HelpPage", @Html.ActionLink(...) }
}
```

This will allow to use arbitrary Razor markup in the values.

However, I would probably recommend that you create a single global dictionary in code, so that you don't need to repeat definitions across pages.  (Depending on how you use it)

Comment: @SLaks,  I read through your writeup on inline helpers but I'm a little confused.  you declare the helper IfLoggedOn to receive a parameter of type `Func<MembershipUser, HelperResult>`.  I gather the second part of that (HelperResult) indicates the return type (does it?) but the first part you never use in the helper.  instead you refer to Membership (.GetUser()) which I'm not sure where it's available from.  Also you pass currentUser to @content(), which I gather is your function but where does that show up? how is it used?

Comment: @ekkis: It's the parameter to the _inline_ helper, named `item`.  I discussed it at the end of the post.

Comment: `MembershipUser` is the parameter passed to the inline helper.  (my first example doesn't use it).  `HelperResult` is the type that the inline helper returns.

Comment: @SLaks, hmm... ok, so in your call `@IfLoggedOn(@<text>Welcome, @item.UserName!</text>)` are you passing @item.UserName to the helper or are you referencing it as something that the helper generates?

Comment: @ekkis: `item` is the parameter to the inline helper.  `@<something>` creates a lambda expression with a single parameter named `item`.

Comment: ok, I'm close.  If I do: `@{ class TestMe { public string Name; public string Surname; } } @helper MyFunc(Func<TestMe, HelperResult> x) { TestMe t = new TestMe() { Name = "x", Surname = "Y" }; @x(t) } @MyFunc(@<b>Name: @item.Name, Surname: @item.Surname</b>)` Razor complains "Method must have a return type" in the call to @MyFunc... something's missing

Comment: ah... seems I can't declare a class in the razor page.  Putting it in the controller file and `@using` the namespace seemed to work.  Now I see how these things work.  Now I just have to figure out how to embed them in a dictionary and use them, as you indicated...

Comment: @SLaks, so going back to the original problem... I have a string in a resource file that looks like this: "See our [Help] page".  it's really a template but the "[Help]" needs to be replaced at runtime by something like `@Html.ActionLink("help", "Help")`... So you recommend: `new Dictionary<string, Func<?, HelperResult>>() { {"Help", @Html.ActionLink("help", "Help")} };` but then, do I foreach the keys and search through the template for the tag? how do I execute the delegate? and how do inline helpers help me here (however cool they are)?

Comment: @ekis: You can declare a class inside an `@functions` block.  http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-6-function-blocks.html  However, you shouldn't.

Comment: You can do the replacements with a regex and a custom `MatchEvaluator` that looks up the delegate from the dictionary.  You probably need to learn about delegates and anonymous functions / lambda expressions.